# Ng repeat with ul li is not coming properly in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angularjs,here I need to get the ul li value from an array,I am getting the value but not getting in proper way.The proper way when you inspect element is

```
<ul>
<li class="parent">Category1</li>
<li class="child">
<ul>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="parent">Category2</li>
<li class="child">
<ul>
<li>four</li>
<li>five</li>
<li>six</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the code below

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul ng-repeat="item in items">
<li class="parent" ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">{{key}}</li>
<li ng-repeat="(key, val) in item" class="child">
<ul>
<li>{{val}}</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

### script

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.items = {"filter":{"Category1":{"value":["one","two","three"]},"Category2":{"value":["four","five","six"]}}}
console.log($scope.items.filter);
});
```

Comment: trying to loop over `item` in view but it is `items` in scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this to get the ul li value from an array:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(x, y) in items.filter">
<li class="parent"><b>{{x}}</b></li>
<li class="child">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="p in y.value">{{p}}</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/D8M1U81tVz3UuzjWathk?p=preview
Hope it helps!